# Grep a file pattern and match it against another file

Tags: grep

I've been fighting with grep all day and still couldn't figure this out.

I have 2 files. 1 with the looks like this:

```
abc-123
def-456
ghi-789
....
```

and my 2nd file is an output from a database that contains those values.
My question is how can I get line by line the value on the 1st file, match it against the 2nd file and print the matching lines?

I've tried fgrep, egrep, ... but can't figure out what I need to do.

Kind Regards,

Comment: `grep -f file1 file2`?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, unfortunately also tried that and there's no output / error to debug further...

Comment: Add output of `file` command to your question: `file file1 file2`

Comment: file1.csv: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
file2.csv:  ASCII text